# Tomcat failing to communicate with Artemis MQ

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, activemq-artemis, tomcat9

I wanted to schedule a message delay using JMS. For that I'm using JMS 2.0 with Artemis MQ and the message is scheduled successfully in compile time but when I deploy it in Tomcat and try to send the message with a delay it says:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: setDeliveryDelay requires JMS 2.0

I'm guessing that the Tomcat isn't able to communicate properly with the Artemis server I have setup. So I have two servers setup in my system: Tomcat and Artemis. Is it because Tomcat can't communicate with Artemis? If so, then why does my spring boot in-built Tomcat server detects Artemis but my standalone Tomcat doesn't?

My source code for the JMS message sender is:

```
@Service
public class TransferServiceImpl implements TransferService {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Override
    public void transfertoJMS(Transaction transaction) {
        System.out.println("Sending a transaction.");

        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryDelay(20000);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, transaction);
    }
}
```

My `pom.xml` is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.stargate.transferfund</groupId>
<artifactId>TransferFund</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>TransferFund</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <startClass>org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication</startClass>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for test case, in memory db -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JMS related dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>artemis-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My `application.properties` is:

```
server.port=${port:8085}

# database config
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ach_stargate
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

# jms config
jms.queue.destination=TransactionQueue
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=localhost
spring.artemis.port=61616
spring.artemis.user=admin
spring.artemis.password=admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a conflict with two conflicting dependencies. The following dependency [is for ActiveMQ 5.x](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-broker)(!):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Spring is probably finding the [JMS 1.0 spec](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec) from that dependency which is overriding the `JMS 2.0` spec on your classpath and giving you that `java.lang.IllegalStateException` when spring looks for the necessary JMS interface to use when starting up the `ConnectionFactory`.

If you want an embedded broker, the `spring-boot-starter-artemis` already contains it, so you should be able to remove that `activemq-broker` dependency without a problem.